# Right clicking a link -- unable to select menu element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to right click a link and choose "Open link in new tab" from the menu the menu. This code should work but is not working.

```
// Create chromedriver.
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

// Bring up the jQuery demos page.
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://jqueryui.com/demos/");

// Create the Actions object.   
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

// Right click on "build a theme" link and open it in a new tab.
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/p[1]/a[1]"));
action.ContextClick(elem)
    .SendKeys(Keys.Down)
    .SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
    .Perform();
```

The right click happens but Selenium does not open the page in a new tab. It opens it in the existing tab.

How can I get the right click to open the page in a new tab?

### ADDENDUM:

The code below works and opens a link in a new tab but it is not an ideal solution

```
            action.ContextClick(elem)
                  .SendKeys(Keys.Control)
                  .SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
                  .Perform();
```

For instance, I can't open the page in a new window if I wanted to.

Comment: You can use IJavaScriptExecutor as an alternate option from Action class.

Comment: How though? I could call window.open to open the page in a new window but that is not the same thing as actually picking it from the list that pops up after I right-click on a link. What if I wanted to click "Save link as .."  what then?